# if statement unusual behavior

Tags: php, if-statement, symfony

Heyho,

I have a little website and want to create a pdf out of it. For this I use dompdf and some basic php:

```
/**
* @Route ("/generatePDF/{php}", name="generatePDF")
*/
public function generatePDFAction($php)
{
   $isPHP = $php;

   if($isPHP == true)
   {
      $lang = "php";
   }else
   {
      $lang = "js";
   }

   //open a link with $lang and get it's html (=> $html)

   //Just for testing, normally it's a working websites html-code
   $html = $isPHP;

   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
   $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
   $dompdf->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
   $dompdf->render();
   $pdf = $dompdf->output();

   //$isPHP = false;

   if($isPHP == true)
   {
      file_put_contents("downloads/rulesphp.pdf", $pdf);
      unset($dompdf);
      return new Response($this -> redirect('/downloads/rulesphp.pdf'));
   }else
   {
      file_put_contents("downloads/rulesjs.pdf", $pdf);
      unset($dompdf);
      return new Response($this -> redirect('/downloads/rulesjs.pdf'));
   }
}
```

then call it:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('generatePDF', {'php': 'true'}) }}">PDF aktualisieren</a>
```

or

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('generatePDF', {'php': 'false'}) }}">PDF aktualisieren</a>
```

whether I want the php or the js rules.

`$isPHP` is a boolean I handover to the function. The first if-statement works like charm, it only breaks at the end... 
$html is normally the websites html, I just set it to `$isPHP` for testing purpose (to see if `$isPHP` is `true/false`). Now the problem:

Whenever I run my code it creates and redirects me to a rulesphp.pdf, whether or not `$isPHP` is set to "true" or "false".

*Sidenote*: When I uncomment the "`//$isPHP = false`" - line it creates a "rulesjs.pdf", as expected, but if I comment it in again or delete it, it won't go back to it's old behavior (as if `$isPHP` is always `true` -> creating rulesphp.pdf, regardless of what `$isPHP` is set), it just keeps the "creating rulesjs.pdf / `$isPHP` is always `false`"-behavior.

*Sidenote2*: `$isPHP` is set correctly, so if it's true, then the pdfs content is true (because of `$html = $isPHP`), if it's false the pdfs content is false, too.

Comment: if you compare to boolean, you probably should use === or !== which also compares the time. I don't get the relationship between $isPHP and $html

Comment: why you expect `$isPHP` to be `false`, while it is string with html?

Comment: $isPHP is a boolean I handover to my function.

Comment: So, you generate pdf with a boolean content? `$html = $isPHP` is assignment, so if your pdf generates correctly - `$isPHP` was a html string.

Comment: edited my question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: add how you call it, please. both cases

Comment: just add `var_dump($php)` to start of function to see if you pass `(string) "false"` here

Comment: `if ($isPHP) { echo 'CREATING PHP'; ... } else { echo 'CREATING JS'; ... }` – do a ***simple*** test to figure out which side is being executed, don't rely on overly complex and third-hand information. There's very little chance something is wrong with the `if` itself, more likely something is wrong with the much more complex code following it.

Comment: Yeah) it's string `"false"` from a routings) It evaluates to true.

Comment: but when it's a string, why does the first if-statement which sets $lang work like it's intended? I mean if I want the js, the $lang correctly outputs "js", if I want the php, $lang correctly outputs "php".

Comment: It's just because everybody lies. ;)

Comment: the mystery of php... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Route ("/generatePDF/{php}", name="generatePDF")`

Your routing pass you string parameters. So, if you call it by `/generatePDF/true`, `/generatePDF/false` urls - you receive strings.

Use:

```
$isPHP === 'true'
```

or `$isPHP = $php === 'true'`

Comment: with $isPHP === 'true' it works without problems. Still wondering why the first if-statement which sets $lang has already worked before.